# How much more can I push current past the rating in a magnet wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, current-rating

If I have a chart like [this](https://www.remingtonindustries.com/content/Remington%20Copper%20and%20Magnet%20Wire%20Data%20Chart.pdf) that shows the current limit for different gauges of wound magnet wire, how much could I push the current over the limit for a short amount of time? I'm assuming these ratings would be for keeping current going through the wire indefinitely, so if I would only have it on for 15 or so seconds before turning it off and letting it fully cool down, how much more would I be able to go past the rating? Take 24 AWG wire for example, the chart rates it at 577 mA, if I only ran it for 15 seconds, could I push it to a full amp? Maybe even two? Keep in mind the wire is coiled, so it shares heat between itself, and it is also around a ferrite core, which can act as a heat sink. If it matters the core is rectangular and the part I'm wrapping around is 18mm * 28mm * 14mm.

Comment: 15 s is **long** for most diameters that you'd call "magnet wire"; that's pretty much "indefinitely". You can however push it how far you want, you just have to live with it getting hot, potentially burning its insulation or melting; what is permissible fully depends on your appplication, and thermal situation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm fine with anything less than damaging the insulation and causing a short. In that case do the numbers on the chart look like the upper limit, or do I still have some wiggle room?

Comment: Its resistance is 84 mOhm/m at room temperature so you can estimate power dissipated in the whole coil which will give you an idea of its temperature rise. This does not take into account skin effect or core losses. If there's one layer of wire and airflow from a fan blowing on it you may get away with a lot more current. If you got an infrared thermometer, you can just check.

Comment: I can't tell you what your isolation can withstand, nor can I tell you how well your wire is able to dissipate heat, so again, this is all up to you. And I explained that yes, you have "wiggle room", as in that you're thermally limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small coils, the only realistic current-related destruction mechanism is thermal, the wire gets too hot and destroys the insulation (it's only for industrial-sized coils that Lorentz force becomes a problem).

There are two limiting cases for heating

1. Long to infinite time, isothermal, all the heat is dissipated
2. Short, adiabatic, all the heat goes to raising the temperature of the copper

Although in practice, all pulse lengths fall somewhere between these two extremes, many approximate to one or the other, and either extreme will give you a worst case if temperature rise is being reduced by both mechanisms.

15 seconds is 'short' (ish), for many coil geometries, and the adiabatic approximation will give you a safe current. For this limiting case, the I<sup>2</sup>t is constant. The power dissipated is proportional to the I<sup>2</sup>R, the total energy dumped in the wire is that times the pulse length.

Note this is independent of how the coil is wound, or what on, as it ignores heat loss to the environment. Any actual loss of heat will just result in a lower temperature for the windings.

To use I<sup>2</sup>t mathematically, you need to know the resistivity and heat capacity of your wire (easily obtainable with a trivial search), and estimate an upper safe working temperature rise for your insulation, or an educated guess if you you don't have a data sheet for your wire. With those, you can compute an I<sup>2</sup>t for your wire.

I'll see if I can find a ready-calculated I<sup>2</sup> for copper and some temperature rises. If not, I'll do the calculation (it's about time I did) and post it later.

To use I<sup>2</sup>t empirically, pulse your coil with a low current and short pulse, then measure the temperature rise. You can do this by measuring the before and after resistance, and noting it increases by about 0.4% per degree for copper. Repeat with increasing current and/or pulse length until you reach a temperature rise you're comfortable with. Plot I<sup>2</sup>t against temperature rise, it should be more or less linear for 'short' pulses. For large temperature rises, the change of copper resistivity with temperature will bend the graph a little.

[this link](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electrical-circuit-protection/fuses/solution-center/bus-ele-tech-lib-conductor-protection-wire-cable-protection-2.pdf) from Eaton gives the I<sup>2</sup>t for 14 AWG wire (2.08 mm<sup>2</sup>) as 47346 for a limiting temperature of 150 C. Your wire is 24 AWG, or 0.205 mm<sup>2</sup>, roughly 1/10th the area, so 1/100th the I<sup>2</sup>t at 473. For a 15 s pulse, that an I<sup>2</sup> of 473/15 = 31.5, or 5.6 A. Which sounds awfully high to me, I'll try to verify or refute that later.

OK, let's do the sums. I'm lousy at algebra and doing everything in strictly SI units, so I hope you'll bear with going concrete too quickly, and working with 1 m length of 24 AWG wire and grams. Figures from wikipedia 'copper' page, approximated in places

Area of 24 AWG wire = 0.205 mm2

Copper density 9000 kg/m3
Copper heat capacity 24.4 J/mol.K
Copper molar weight 63.5 g
Thermal capacity of copper/g = 24.4/63.5 = 0.38 J/K
Mass of 1 m of 24 AWG wire = 0.205u*9k = 1.8 g
Thermal capacity of 1 m of 24 AWG = 1.8 * 0.38 = 0.68 J/K

Copper resistivity = 17 mohm for 1m of 1 mm2 area wire
Resistance of 24 AWG wire/m = 17/0.2 = 85 mohm

Power per m of wire at 1 A = 85 mW
Rate of temperature rise = .085/0.68 = 0.125 K/s
Time through 125 K (to 150 C starting from 25 C) = 125/0.125 = 1000 s

Which gives an I<sup>2</sup>t of 1000 for 24 AWG wire.

I would have hoped for better agreement with the 473 figure from Eaton's data, but, at least they are in the same ball-park (in engineering, within a factor of 2 is often considered 'equal'). Note that the resistivity of copper increases by 10% every 25 C, so you would expect a reduction in average I<sup>2</sup>t over the temperature range of a few 10s of percent, pushing this figure lower. The thermal capacity of copper increases a little as the temperature rises, which will offset some of this drop.

I<sup>2</sup>t = 1000 would imply a current of sqrt(1000/15) = 8 A for a 15 second pulse, to a final 150 C. This is so hot it would burn your finger, and this is for a single pulse, you would need to let the coil cool to room temperature before repeating it.

Can anybody else confirm my rough calculation of I<sup>2</sup>t = 1000, extrapolated from 25 C figures, for a 125 C temperature rise, for 24 AWG copper?

Comment: OK, so let's decorate the back of an envelope with scribbles: look at a winding in the middle of the pack, which is surrounded by windings heating up at pretty much the same rate. Copper has a density of roughly 9 g/cm³, AWG 24 has a cross-section of 0.2 mm² = 2/1000 cm², so that at a packing density of circles of 0.85 including enamel and circle packing density, through a 1 cm² cross-section through the winding bulk N=588 parallel wires of length 1cm fit. Through each of these wires 1 A flows, 1 cm has 0.84 mΩ of resistance, leading to a ohmic loss power of N·I²·R=588·1A²·0.84mA = 490 W.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  You can ignore all the packing density cruft, and just assume an infinite chunk of copper as the limiting case. You don't seem to be assuming a final temperature. What does your 490 W mean in terms of I2t?

Comment: let me quickly finish this noting, then I'll address that :)

Comment: So, we said we had a mass of 9 g/cm³ for pure copper, with our 0.85 packing density, that's about 7.6 g that we're heating with 490 W. Copper has a specific heat capacity of C=385 J/kg/K; so we heat up by T=490W·15s/(7.6·10⁻³kg) / C = 2511 K.

Comment: I don't think we can assume this to be a very static situation. It's more of a "glows very bright and splatters molten metal in all directions" situation, which is definitely not happening in reality. So, I must be doing something wrong in my calculations, but I'm not sure *what*. Then again, if 588 parallel wires in 1 cm² is right (and that seems to be at least in the right order of magnitude), then we have half a kA per square centimeter as current density, and that's definitely quite a bit.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am doing this for the adiabatic limit where no heat is lost. Of course in a dynamic situation, more heat will be lost to ambient allowing a higher current.

Comment: well, a 1 cm³ cube won't get rid of 490W on short notice, either

Answer (score 2):

Note: Outside of relatively narrow regulatory contexts, wires don't really have current "ratings" because the maximum permissible current is dependent on so many other factors.

Fusing current for AWG24 copper wire is approximately 29A. But most 'magnet wire' insulations will not withstand molten copper temperatures.

So it's mostly the insulation you'll be worried about. You need to have a specification for the maximum operating temperature of the insulation. Polyimide (eg. Kapton) insulation may be good for well over 200°C. Some types of PU insulation, as low as 90°C.

If you're starting off at (say) 75°C maximum, that's around an order of magnitude different \$\Delta T\$, depending on the insulation type, so **not** small.

[Here](https://essexfurukawa.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Essex-Wire-White-Paper-Thermal-Class-EN.pdf) is some detailed information on various insulation types and reliability impact of the temperature range (and some discussion of momentary overloads). For example (emphasis added):

> Polyimide film is very resistant to high temperatures, and is the
> product of choice where the magnet wire may be subjected to
> continuously high operating temperatures or *subject to intermittent
> severe overloads*.
>
> Some typical uses include:
>
> - Fractional and integral horsepower motors
> - High temperature continuous duty coils and relays
> - Hermetic and sealed units

I suggest using the delta-resistance method to get some idea of the average temperature of the wire, keeping in mind that the hottest point will be hotter than the average (how much depends on a lot of factors). If you think the inner part of the coil is going to be the peak part it's pretty easy to embed a bead or ribbon thermocouple in the coil (but may not be feasible if the voltages are high).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to work it out from the specific heat capacity of copper. That tells you how many joules it takes to heat up a certain mass of copper (usually 1 kg) by 1°C. Looking on google, it tells me that it has a figure of 385 J/kg°C.

Then you have to work out what heat power (\$I^2R\$) is being produced by the magnet wire. This tells you how many joules per second are produced. Factor in the mass of the copper wire (your coil) and that will tell you what final temperature the coil will rise to over a given period of time carrying the current.

Anything over 200°C and I'd start to worry about the insulation on the magnet wire (unless you know it is high-temperature type).

But, you could easily be out by a factor of (guessing) ten due to the other thermal masses (that's basically what specific heat capacity is all about really). I think taking this approach will give you the worst case scenario though.

---

Let's say that the wire dissipates 10 watts at a certain current. That's ten joules per second and, over 15 seconds, that's 150 joules. Let's say the copper wire mass is 10 grammes. That looks like the a temperature rise of 39°C.

Of course if the power dissipated by the winding is 100 watts it will rise 390°C and that will be a lot too much for most situations. And, the wires under layers of other wires will likely get a lot warmer than wires on the outside of the winding.